# form with multi select option and a search box

Tags: html

i'm creating a tour site where people can select a number destination, date, number of children and the price range to see if that type of a tour is available, then redirects to that page to preview and sign up. how can i set up that using a multi select option and  a search box,?

This is the simple html form but i can't expand on this

```
<select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary md-form" multiple searchable="Search here..">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="3">France</option>
  <option value="4">Poland</option>
  <option value="5">Japan</option>
</select>
<label class="mdb-main-label">Label example</label>
<button class="btn-save btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Select should be named.

Comment: thats the code i tried but i couldn't get to the desired solution, looking for a way to create a code to my problem i stated on top..!

Comment: And that code works. It is a multiselect, you probably don't know how to use it, you need to drag to select multiple or click with ctrl key to add new selection. If it's something else, still unclear what you are asking for. No one will make the whole project for you in here. It's not a programmers charity organization. I personally use this jQuery plugin for mutiselects: http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples

Answer (score -1):

you can use this jquery plugin to implement multi select option in html using jquery:

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select